# How to locate matches in two dataframes with contains

Tags: python, string, dataframe, field, contains

How caqn I locate a string from a dataframe field (df1), in a string from another dataframe field (df2)? Is it possible with the command contains?

Example:

```
df1[field1]="CEG"

df2[field2]=" CRAT Z.8.1 and Z.8.2 (INC-0022540490) M-137 --- NT[002][URB:1-CEG PET:GR.7:C2-98-S1] --- "
```

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you.

Comment: That command is probably documented somewhere. What did you find reading that documentation? Also, why are you using all uppercase in your title?

Comment: Sorry for the capital letters, I thought I had to put it that way